# Recaptcha v2 как подключить в OpenCart 3.0 ОШИБКА: неверный ключ

Tags: opencart, recaptcha

Нашел Recaptcha, подключил, вставил ключи, теперь выдает ошибку, ОШИБКА: неверный ключ. При том что на сайте уже была капча. на другом не было, мы подключили и там и там ошибка. Пробовали разную версию капчи.